# Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to deploy my application, but it shows error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.springapp.mvc.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship: com.springapp.mvc.models.User.ads

I think I wrong mapped something:

Model User:

```
      @Entity
            public class User implements UserDetails {
               private int id;
               private Set<Ad> ads;
               private Set<Ad> favourites;

               @Id
               @GeneratedValue
               @Column(name = "id")
               public int getId() {
                  return id;
               }

               public void setId(int id) {
                  this.id = id;
               }

                 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @Where(clause="is_deleted <> '1'")
            @JsonIgnore
            public Set<Ad> getAds() {
                return ads;
            }

            public void setAds(Set<Ad> ads) {
                this.ads = ads;
            }

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
            @JsonIgnore
            @JoinTable(name= "favourite",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="ad_id")})
            public Set<Ad> getFavourites() {
                return favourites;
            }

            public void setFavourites(Set<Ad> favourites) {
                this.favourites = favourites;
            }
    }
```

Ad model:

```
     @Entity
        public class Ad {

        private Integer id;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id")
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ads")
        public List<User> getFavouriteUsers() {
            return favouriteUsers;
        }

        public void setFavouriteUsers(List<User> favouriteUsers) {
            this.favouriteUsers = favouriteUsers;
        }
}
```

Where can be problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In User.java, you have defined OneToMany relationship for "ads" with Ads.java

```
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @Where(clause="is_deleted <> '1'")
        @JsonIgnore
        public Set<Ad> getAds() {
            return ads;
        }
```

However, in Ads.java you have defined ManyToMany relationship for same

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ads")
    public List<User> getFavouriteUsers() {
        return favouriteUsers;
    }
```

Make sure to use the same mapping in both classes to avoid this error

Comment: so, how I need to change my code, that it will work.  Sorry, I'm new in Hibernate.... I'm not fully understand Hibernate

Comment: Why do you need both ads and favourites in the User.java? Elaborate your DB design and may be then I can help you out with this

Comment: thanks, it works, I changes mappedBy to another value